# Подсветить определенные строки при наведении на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, dom

Есть список:

- Строка1
- Строка2
- ...
- СтрокаN

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на кнопку `button1` подсвечивались допустим 1,3,6 строки, а при наведении на button2 2,4?

Верстка:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id=1>Строка1</div>
    <div id=2>Строка2</div>
    <div id=3>Строка3</div>
    <div id=4>Строка4</div>
    <div id=5>Строка5</div>
</div>
<button class="knopka">Button1</button>
<button class="knopka">Button2</button>
```

Comment: а можно верстку?

Comment: А кнопок в верстку не завезли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные о том, каким строками манипулировать можно сохранить в `data-` атрибуте

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.knopka');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('data-rows'));
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      document.getElementById(data[i]).classList.add('active');
  });
  buttons[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('data-rows'));
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      document.getElementById(data[i]).classList.remove('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="1">Строка1</div>
  <div id="2">Строка2</div>
  <div id="3">Строка3</div>
  <div id="4">Строка4</div>
  <div id="5">Строка5</div>
</div>
<button class="knopka" data-rows="[1, 3, 5]">Button1</button>
<button class="knopka" data-rows="[2, 4]">Button2</button>
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое. Я просто не мог понять,как хранить данные о этих строках,которые надо подсветить.

Answer (score 0):

Для каждой кнопки в data-rows можно указывать через запятую номера элементов.

```js
const allRows = document.querySelectorAll('#main div')
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.knopka')

buttons.forEach(el => {
  const myRows = el.dataset.rows.split(',')
  const myRowsEl = []
  
  for (let myRow of myRows)
    myRowsEl.push(allRows[myRow - 1])
    
  const toggle = () => 
    myRowsEl.forEach(el => 
      el.classList.toggle('light')
    )

  el.onmouseenter = el.onmouseleave = toggle
})
```

```css
.light {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div>Строка1</div>
  <div>Строка2</div>
  <div>Строка3</div>
  <div>Строка4</div>
  <div>Строка5</div>
</div>
<button class="knopka" data-rows="1,3,5">Button1</button>
<button class="knopka" data-rows="2,4">Button2</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо и за ваш код